# Filtering arrays in excel

Tags: arrays, excel, filtering, formula

Let's say I have the following data in excel:

```
      A      B
1  Tomato   Car
2  Apple    Hat
3  Tomato   Melon
4  Tomato   Paper
```

Using the following array formula in excel:

```
{=IF(A1:A4="B";B1:B4)}
```

I am able to get the following array

```
{Car,FALSE,Melon,Paper}
```

How do I get rid of the 'FALSE' value, so that I end up with

```
{Car,Melon,Paper}
```

Answer (score 2):

Modify the formula to get a null, using the False argument in the IF sentence.

Something like this should work for you:

```
=IF($A$1:$A$4="Tomato";$B$1:$B$4;"")
```

This is what I get after applying formula:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't really work for me. In the real world, the data that i'm after is only a small subset of the full set. So I need to get an array that contains only the relevant data and no null or FALSE values